# Sessions in .net6 after upgrading from .net4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I just upgraded my .net 4.8 MVC web app to .net6.
I used Sessions to store objects.
for example the User class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }

}
```

This is how I set the session:

```
Session[Consts.CURRENTUSER] = userFromDb;
```

This is how I use it:

```
User _currentUser = Session[Consts.CURRENTUSER] as User;
```

Now, after the upgrade it does not compile. I get the following error:

> Error CS0103  The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

If i use the following `HttpContext.Session[Consts.CURRENTUSER] as User` it still does not allow the the above use.

Will appreciate an example on how I will be able to use the above scenario in .net core.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Does it fail to compile, does it throw an exception, is `_currentUser` null, what **exactly** happens? Also, did you enable sessions in the startup?

Comment: You are correct - I mean doesn't compile. I did not enabled sessions in the startup.

Comment: Well... where exactly are you trying to write the third code block? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: As a complement to @CamiloTerevinto answer you need to follow check documentation : 
before using session you need to add  an IDistributedMemoryCache please check  Microsoft's documentation  :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0), I followed [this guide from step 4](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-session-in-asp-net-core/) to allow the usage of Sessions.
Then, in order to use complex objects in .net core I followed [this link](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/store-complex-objects-in-asp-net-core-session/) which provided an extension method that implementing the use of complex objects in sessions.